# JavaFX - Setting text values with special characters programatically

Tags: java, javafx, openjdk-21

I'm building a java application on JDK 21, all files seemingly being UTF-8 encoded (it says on the bottom right [image]), but I can't programatically set the text value of a JavaFX UI element to anything containing special characters like "äöüß".
It displays them like "ÃœÃœÃœÃ".

Hardcoded values in the FXML-file are displayed correctly though.

I can't find a solution for this, except for replacing every special character with the Unicode escape sequence, but I'd assume there's a better solution.

Comment: This works fine for me (just using, e.g., `new Label("äöüß")`.) Can you create and post a [mre]?

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: What text editor or IDE are you using?

Comment: And what is your host OS locale setting?

Comment: It appears your Java compiler doesn’t know your source file is UTF-8.  If using the command-line, add `-encoding UTF-8`.  Otherwise, change the properties of your project in your IDE, so that source files are treated as UTF-8 files.

Comment: The screenshot looks like Idea.  If you generate a new JavaFX project in Idea of Maven type, it puts this in the `pom.xml` -> `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>` in the properties section.  And then when the Maven project is synched with Idea I guess it will used be used as the default encoding for the project.  [Maven documentation recommends this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html).  If using some other build tool, then it will probably have a similar method.

Comment: When I run a default generated Maven JavaFX project in Idea, in the console it shows the Java command with a `...` next to it you can click to expand the command.  In the expanded command it has: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8`.  The sun stuff is for the output console, but the file encoding is for files read.  Just generating a new application, going to the generated HelloController.java and changing the text set on button click to `"Welcome to JavaFX Application! äöüß"`, produces the desired output on button click.

Comment: Also, since [JEP 400](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400) released with [Java 18](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding#6-default-charset-since-java-18), Java is UTF-8 by default, so you don't really need to do anything specific in Java to use UTF-8 if targeting a modern Java release - it should just work as long as the right fonts are available and the files involved have all been correctly encoded to UTF-8.

Comment: @Maxim Tell us if you use Maven or Gradle. If so, post your POM for Maven, or equivalent for Gradle.

Comment: I had to put compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8' into the build.gradle file, then it worked